# Connect to neo4j directly using node.js without using REST API

Tags: node.js, neo4j

Is there any way to connect neo4j directly using node.js without neo4j REST API.

Whenever I am trying to create multiple node in neo4j using node.js (asynchronously), after some time, server gives the connection error, it is because multiple requests are sending to the server simultaneously.

I have increased the org.neo4j.server.webserver.maxthreads to 10000, still not working.